# weird behavior on submit entity reference view widget items

Tags: ajax, entities

When creating a content type (i use seven as admin theme) i have 2 fields they are entity reference.
I use entity reference view widget to select the items in both fields.
In first field appears a radios items list and after selecting one item when i click «submit» it works and the selected items appear as values in the field.
This is the ajax response to clicking the Submit button:

[image]

But when, after selecting one or some of the checkboxes for the second field, i press the Submit button, nothing happens.
The modal window doesn't close and the selected items don't populate the field :(
This is the response to the Submit button for field two:

[image]

Can anybody point out a clue of the problem?